# SQL Group By Client Query

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains client information. This table holds the License type information against each client.

[image]

I wish to query this table to only find records of clients who have Licence Type as 2 or 1 and nothing else. A  client can have licence type 1, 2 and 3 such clients should not qualify in the result set.

Appreciate your any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select clientid
from t
group by clientid
having sum(case when licensetype not in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of unacceptable license types for each client.  The `= 0` says that there are none.

EDIT:

Perhaps this really does what you want:

```
having max(licensetype) = 2 and
       min(licensetype) >= 1  -- not clear if this is necessary
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The query does give me the results for licence types 1 or 2. There are actually 5 licence types (1.2.3.4.5). I tried editing the query to return results where clients have only 1 and 2. Any suggestions.

Comment: @Ravinesh . . . This query should return clients that have *only* license types 1 and 2 and nothing else (well, perhaps `NULL` as well, if that is possible).

Comment: Yeah i tried the query, however clients with only licence type 1 also appear in the list. I am concerned about licence type 2. For the client to qualify in the result set: Licence type cannot be greater than 2, it can be less than 2 but 2 must be inclusive.